# Laravel PSR-4 not loading classes automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am using a custom folder in app directory which contains Billing, Exceptions, Repositories etc. Here is my directory structure...

```
app
  -iw
     -Billing
         -BillingInterface.php
         -StripeBilling.php
     -Exceptions
     -Repositories
     -macros.php
```

composer.json

```
"psr-4": {
        "iw\\" : "app/iw"
    },
```

ran command `composer dump-autoload -o`

Classes

```
// app/iw/BillingInterface.php (location)

<?php namespace iw\Billing;

interface BillingInterface {}
```

And

```
// app/iw/StripeBilling.php (location)

<?php namespace iw\Billing;

class StripeBilling {

    public function bill()
    {
        dd('billing');
    }

}
```

I am getting class not found error, even i noticed that `vendor/composer/autoload_ps4.php` is not updating with this new folder. Please help. thanks

Comment: Well structure look all correct, composer gives 0 errors? Out of curiosity ``"psr-4"`` declaration is in the autoload tree? Tried to do a composer self-update?

Comment: @arma yes composer gives 0 errors. And i tried composer self-update

Comment: just made identical test and it worked as expected for me.

Comment: @arma you know what it just worked, but you would have to tell me 'WHY' please... I am posting answer...

Answer (score 2):

Add "app/iw" in "classmap".

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php",
        "app/iw"
    ],
    "psr-4" : {
        "iw\\" : "app/iw"
    }
}
```

and run

```
 composer dump-autoload -o
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this json file and it worked...

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"iw\\" : "app/iw" },
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    }
```

But please suggest why it worked after adding `"psr-4": {"iw\\" : "app/iw" }` in autoload section.

Comment: Because that's what autoload do? It adds mapping for your php autoloaders. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: Thanks @arma for great help, and one more thing, i have put custom macros.php(for coutry select field) inside iw folder but i am getting this error... `Method selectCountry does not exist`, it woks if i put it inside app/ and referent it in global.php but not loading from autoloader, or am i missing something.

Comment: Great it worked for you, about macros, yeah you can't load them from composer straight forward (well i'm sure someone can do it, but it will not be pretty) as it will be loaded before FORM or HTML facades. All you can do is load them in your start.php or global.php.